# Is String not considered an object?

Tags: java, interface

What I do not understand is why I am getting an error compiling my code when a String is in fact an object, and the compiler is saying otherwise. I dont know why I keep getting this error message

```
  symbol:   method compareTo(Object)
  location: variable least of type Object
.\DataSet.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
   else if(maximum.compareTo(x) < 0)
```

here is the code. I'm trying to utilize the class comparable to allow two objects to use the compareTo method. In the tester, I'm just trying to use a basic string object to compare.

```
public class DataSetTester
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    String man = "dog";
    String woman = "cat";
    ds.add(man);
    ds.add(woman);
    System.out.println("Maximum Word: " + ds.getMaximum());


 }
}
```

Class:

```
public class DataSet implements Comparable 
{
 private Object maximum;
 private Object least;
 private int count;
 private int answer;

 public void add(Object x)
 {

   if(count == 0){
     least = x;
     maximum = x;
   }
   else if(least.compareTo(x) > 0)
     least = x;
   else if(maximum.compareTo(x) < 0)
    maximum = x;
   count++;
 }

 public int compareTo(Object anObject)
 {
     return this.compareTo(anObject);
 }

 public Object getMaximum()
 {
  return maximum;
 }

 public Object getLeast()
 {
   return least;
 }
}
```

Comparable Interface:

```
public interface Comparable
{
    public int compareTo(Object anObject);
}
```

Comment: Are you implementing *your own* `Comparable` class which is different from `java.lang.Comparable`? I ask because the code you posted for `Comparable` is very different from the genericized modern `java.lang.Comparable`...

Comment: brief answer: a String is an Object, but an Object is not necessarily a String. Object does not implement Comparable, so Objects cannot be compareTo()'ed. Cast the objects to Strings or use generics.

Comment: @irrelephant: or simply declare the variables as Comparable type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `DataSet` implements `Comparable`, but `Object` doesn't.

Instead of storing `Object`s, you want to store `Comparable`s. However, if you do get this to compile, you will get into an infinite loop right here:

```
public int compareTo(Object anObject) 
{
    // Yeah, never stop loopin'!
    return this.compareTo(anObject);
}
```

It's recommended that in newer code, you use the generic `Comparable<T>` interface. Your code would then look like this:

```
public class DataSet implements Comparable<DataSet>  
{  
 private String maximum;  
 private String least;  
 private int count;  
 private int answer;  

 public void add(String x)  
 {  

   if(count == 0){  
     least = x;  
     maximum = x;  
   }  
   else if(least.compareTo(x) > 0)  
     least = x;  
   else if(maximum.compareTo(x) < 0)  
    maximum = x;  
   count++;  
 }  

 public int compareTo(DataSet anObject)  
 {  
     // I don't really know how you want this to work.
     // Come up with your own criteria on what makes a DataSet greater or less than
     // another one.
     count - anObject.count
 }  

 // Good practice to include this if you're doing a compareTo.
 @Override
 public boolean equals(Object other)
 {
     return (other instanceof DataSet) && compareTo((DataSet)other) == 0;
 }

 public String getMaximum()  
 {  
  return maximum;  
 }  

 public String getLeast()  
 {  
   return least;  
 }  
}
```

Edit - just saw that you're comparing strings. In that case, you don't really need `DataSet` to implement `Comparable`. However, if you do need it for something else, what I wrote still stands.

Comment: This seems more like the answer I need although what I need to do is allow this data class to acceopt Comparable objects, which will be tested through String. Will this work that way?

Comment: I changed it a little so you add `String`s instead of `DataSet`s, which is what I think you're looking for. However I'm still not quite sure what you're trying to do.
Basically - if you're going to have lots of `DataSet`s, make it implement `Comparable`.
If you have one `DataSet` that sorts a bunch of `String`s, then you're probably looking for something along the lines of @duffymo's solution.

Answer (score 7):

Of course String is an Object.

Comparable is generic now.  Why do you feel the need to make those references Object if they are type String?  Your code is poor; it's not a Java problem.

I don't see why DataSet needs to implement Comparable.  You just need to compare incoming Strings as they're added.  Do it this way and you'll fare better:

```
public class DataSet {
    private String maximum;
    private String least;
    private int count;
    private int answer;

    public void add(String x) {  
        if(count == 0){
             least = x;
             maximum = x;
        } else if (least.compareTo(x) > 0) {
             least = x;
        } else if(maximum.compareTo(x) < 0) {
             maximum = x;
        }
        count++;
    }

    public String getMaximum() { return this.maximum; }

    public String getLeast() { return this.least; }

    public int getCount() { return this.count; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

least and maximum are simply Objects, and the Object class doesn't have a `compareTo(...)` method, simple as that. least and maximum need to be declared Comparable, not Object. And as written, it makes no sense declaring DataSet to implement the Comparable interface since there are no DataSet objects present and certainly none being compared.

Answer (score 2):

java.lang.Object does not have a compareTo() method.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is an infinite loop in you code:

```
 public int compareTo(Object anObject)
 {
     return this.compareTo(anObject);
 }
```

this method is continuously calling itself.

Regarding your compile error: you have declared variable as `Object`, which obviously does not have a compareTo method.

Answer (score 0):

There is no compareTo() method in [Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html). I guess you're looking for [String.compareTo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.Object%29).

Answer (score 0):

Type checking is done at compile time and not runtime. At compile time, least and maximum are considered to be objects of type Object and not String.